# Windows Server 2008R2 Server Manager Closes (Crashes?) On Starting

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mmc

I have a weird issue on one of my Windows Server 2008R2 machines (running as a VM on VMware 5.5).  The Server Manager MMC app will close on it's own immediately or shortly after starting.  Sometimes you will get to where you can see the Server Manager Window before it closes but usually you don't even get that far.  There are no error messages that I can find either on screen when it closes or in the event logs.  This happens regardless of what user logs in (even the local Administrator) or whether run normally or as an Administrator.  Does MMC generate any log files that I could use to troubleshoot?

Edit:  I did some additional troubleshooting using SysInternals Process Monitor to watch the mmc.exe.  I found that the last thing done before the app closed is:

```
QueryNameInformationFile  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll  SUCCESS  Name: \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
```

After that, all the threads exit and everything is closed properly.  I thought maybe something is wrong with the .NET v2.0 install so I used the .NET Setup Verifier to check and it did not find any issues.  .NET 2.0 SP2, 3.0 SP2, 3.5 SP1, 4 Client, 4 Full, 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2 are all installed on this server.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't find anything in the application / system logs? Should generate something when MMC crashes. Have you tried sfc /scannow? Also although unlikely have you checked task scheduler to see if maybe someone made a task to close it at startup because maybe they couldn't figure out how to disable it?

Comment: There are no messages in the event logs related to MMC.  For the life of me, it looks just like it's closing normally but automatically.  I hadn't thought about the task scheduler thing.  I will look through there in the morning.